# EF Core UseModel() causes the generated table structure primary key to not be the default Identity column

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

Example code: I have set the primary key in the entity configuration class and did not call `ValueGeneratedNever()`:

```cs
_builder.Services.AddDbContext<SlaveDataContext>((sp, options) =>
{
    var modelBuilder = SqlServerConventionSetBuilder.CreateModelBuilder();

    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(SlaveDataContext).Assembly);            

    var readonlyModel = modelBuilder.FinalizeModel();

    options
        .EnableDetailedErrors()
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
        .UseSqlServer(_builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataContext_slave"))
        .UseModel(readonlyModel);
});
```

So, I get a table without identity column.

Just like the results generated through the `OnModelCreating` method without using `UseModel`.